# modify entity in memory without errors when saving poco EF 4.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I need to temporarily modify a collection on an entity in memory without the framework exploding with an error. I have two entities I'm working with. Entity A has a collection that I simply need to remove an item from and add another item I created on the fly to it. Entity B uses that item from entity A to do calculations off of but doesn't hold a reference to it in any of its properties. The problem is when I go to save entity B it explodes because of my in memory changes of entity A. In no way am I trying to save entity A, the framework is just figuring out I made a change to it and throwing this error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

I'm using poco classes and saving each entity individually so I'm confused why when I save entity B the framework is also trying to save entity A. The pocos are all wired up using the EntityTypeConfiguration class if that makes a diff.

Is there a way to tell an individual entity to not track itself for a period of time?

Comment: What do you mean by "*saving each entity individually*"? You can only call `context.SaveChanges` which always saves everything that has been modified in the context/unit of work. How do you save "*individual*" entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch your entity A without tracking. With `DbContext`:

```
var aList = context.As.AsNoTracking();
```

With `ObjectContext` (which you don't use, but anyway)

```
context.As.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
var aList = context.As;
```

Thus, EF will not keep track of any changes on `A`'s, let alone save them.